# Trigger a google swiffy script within jQuery cycle

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, google-swiffy

I'm using multiple instances Google's swiffy SWF conversion tool on a single page and want to activate them one at a time within a jQuery cycle of sequentially named divs (content-1, content-2).

I know you can control the start of each instance via:

```
    stageName.start(true)
```

If they were named sequentially (stageName1, stageName2) could you trigger each animation within the following cycle function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var divs = $('div[id^="content-"]').hide(),
    i = 0;

(function cycle() { 
    divs.eq(i).fadeIn(400)
              .delay(5000)
              .fadeOut(400, cycle);

    i = ++i % divs.length; // increment i, 
                           //   and reset to 0 when it equals divs.length
})();

});// JavaScript Document
```

This is how they are triggered now within each 'content-' div:

```
<script>
var stage2 = new swiffy.Stage(document.getElementById('circle_lines'), circleobject);
stage2.start();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this helps someone else who's using swiffy.

Even though there is no sort of rewind(); method yet, there is a destroy() method.

Inside a jQuery cycle I originally posted I used dynamic global JS variables to constantly start and destroy a new swiffy object.

This enables me to loop through different divs and restart the animation each cycle.

```
if (typeof window["Stage" + i] != 'undefined') {
    window["Stage" + i].destroy();
}

    i = ++i % divs.length; // increment i, 
                           //   and reset to 0 when it equals divs.length


    window["Stage" + i] = new swiffy.Stage(document.getElementById('graph_lines'), swiffyobject);
    window["Stage" + i].start();
```